# SOAP-API partner.jar creation problem

Tags: soap-api

I want to generate partner.jar.

My path is :-

> java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib\wsc-23.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib\tools.jar"com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc partner.wsdl partner.jar

Error: Could not find or load main class partner.wsdl

Comment: Please add a space before **com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc** .  Also, Are you providing fully qualified path for partner WSDL file . Ex: 
java -classpath " C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib\wsc-23.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib\tools.jar" com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc "C:\**<SOMEFOLDER>**/partner.wsdl" "C:\**<SOMEFOLDER>**/partner.jar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some basic instructions in [Instructions for Java Environments (WSC)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_import_wsdl.htm?search_text=Java)

> Java environments access the API through Java objects that serve as proxies for their server-side counterparts. Before using the API, you must first generate these objects from your organization’s WSDL file.
>
> Each SOAP client has its own tool for this process. For WSC, use the `wsdlc` utility.
>
> **Note**
> Before you run `wsdlc`, you must have the WSC JAR file installed on your system and referenced in your classpath.
>
> The basic syntax for wsdlc is:
>
> `java –classpath pathToJAR/wsc-22.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc pathToWsdl/WsdlFilename​ pathToOutputJar/OutputJarFilename`
>
> This command generates an output jar file based on the specified WSDL file.    After the output jar file is created, reference it along with the wsc jar file (for example, wsc-22.jar) in your Java program to create a client application.

In your case the error is indicating that it can't find your partner.wsdl file. Is it in the current directory that you are running the command from? You should have downloaded from your developer edition org in a prior step from under Setup > Develop > API.

If is isn't in the current directory, you may need to add the full path for it in the command.